# Why is eval not bound in REPL?

Tags: clojurescript

I'm learning clojure, I'm trying to experiment in the clojure REPL using shadow-cljs. I thought eval was part of the `clojure.core`, but using this

```
(eval (list + 1 2))
```

produces `Error: cljs.core/*eval* not bound`

I also tried this but got the same error

```
(require `clojure.core)
(clojure.core/eval (list + 1 2))
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are likely using a ClojureScript REPL where `eval` only works as part of self-hosted builds which require [additional setup](https://code.thheller.com/blog/shadow-cljs/2017/10/14/bootstrap-support.html). `clojure.core` is automatically aliased to `cljs.core` as part of the compiler, that is why you get the `cljs.core/*eval*` error.

If you intend to do actual Clojure REPL work you should use

```
shadow-cljs clj-repl
```

which will give you a pure Clojure REPL.